# Ubuntu fails to boot after hibernation

Tags: ubuntu, macintosh, hibernate

I had installed Ubuntu 15.10 in a separate partition on my MBA(MacBook Air 2015 model). I had set it to hibernate on lid-close. It was working all fine, until today it was not able to come back from hibernation.

Is there some way I can boot into it? I think it is failing during loading the hibernation file from the Swap partition. Will formatting swap partition make it boot?

Comment: Please edit and add the output of `fstab` and the following command `cat /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` , How many OS is that installed?

Comment: @GAD3R: OK, I will do that when I get back to my machine. There are only 2 OSes installed -- OSX El Capitan and Ubuntu 15.10. I am using ReFind as the boot manager.

Answer (score 0):

In the boot menu (grub) edit the kernel's command line and remove the parameters `resume` and `resume_offset`. Without that the kernel cannot resume and has to boot fresh.